# No default constructor exists for class but non default passed

Tags: c++, list, constructor, initialization, default

My Thing class is derived from Entity class which has the following constructor

```
    Entity::Entity(string sNames, double xcord, double ycord)
    :m_sName(sNames), m_dX(xcord),m_dY(ycord){}
```

Thing's constructor is

```
    Thing::Thing(string sName, double xcord, double ycord):
    Entity(sName, xcord, ycord),
    m_iHealth(100),m_Weapon(Weapon("Fists", false, 10.0, 5, 1.0, xcord, ycord)){}
```

The problem is I get error "no appropriate default constructor available" on my Thing constructor.  What is the problem I specified to use my Entity constructor not a default.  To make the problem even more confusing for me I have another class derieved from Entity that works

```
    Weapon::Weapon(string sName, bool iMagical, double dRange, int iDamage,double
    dRadius, double dSpawnX, double dSpawnY):
    Entity(sName, dSpawnX, dSpawnY), m_bMagical(iMagical), m_dRange(dRange), m_iDamage(iDamage),
    m_dRadius(dRadius)
{
}
```

That runs without error but it appears to be the same exact thing as my Thing constructor with more variables.  I'm sure I am missing something small but I have been stumped for a while.

You were correct there was some leftover code that didn't get commented out.  It seems strange that and error in member variable deceleration shows up in constructor, but thanks anyway.  It's always the simple things hat get me.

Comment: It might not have the class definition, did you forward declare Entity in Thing's header file, but forget to #include in Thing's cpp file?

Comment: The code you posted is fine. you may call Entity() somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe you have some data member of `Thing` which you forgot to include in your initializer list but which does not have a default constructor.

Comment: please post complete error message

Comment: @john either that, or an additional base class

Comment: Please reduce your program to the smallest complete program that demonstrates the error. See http://sscce.org for more info.

Comment: *Aside*: In your `Thing` constructor, `m_weapon(Weapon(x,y,z))` creates one too many objects. Prefer this:  `m_weapon(x,y,z)`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your `Thing` does not, in fact, have a default constructor and one is required. A program like this might generate an error like you saw.

```
#include <string>
using std::string;

struct Entity {
  std::string m_sName;
  double m_dX, m_dY;
  Entity(std::string, double, double);
};
struct Weapon : Entity {
  bool m_bMagical;
  double m_dRange;
  int m_iDamage;
  double m_dRadius;
  Weapon(std::string, bool, double, int, double, double, double);
};
struct Thing : Entity {
  int m_iHealth;
  Weapon m_Weapon;
  Thing(std::string, double, double);
};


// OP's code starts here
Entity::Entity(string sNames, double xcord, double ycord)
    :m_sName(sNames), m_dX(xcord),m_dY(ycord){}

Thing::Thing(string sName, double xcord, double ycord):
    Entity(sName, xcord, ycord),
    m_iHealth(100),m_Weapon(Weapon("Fists", false, 10.0, 5, 1.0, xcord, ycord)){}

Weapon::Weapon(string sName, bool iMagical, double dRange, int iDamage,double
    dRadius, double dSpawnX, double dSpawnY):
    Entity(sName, dSpawnX, dSpawnY), m_bMagical(iMagical), m_dRange(dRange), m_iDamage(iDamage),
    m_dRadius(dRadius)
{
}
// OP's code ends here

int main () {
  Thing th;
}
```

Under g++, the precise error is:

```
th.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
th.cc:40: error: no matching function for call to ‘Thing::Thing()’
th.cc:27: note: candidates are: Thing::Thing(std::string, double, double)
th.cc:16: note:                 Thing::Thing(const Thing&)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Thing::m_Weapon` is declared as `Weapon` and not as `Weapon*`, `Weapon&`, or equivilent, then you need to change this:

```
m_Weapon(Weapon("Fists", false, 10.0, 5, 1.0, xcord, ycord))
```

To this

```
m_Weapon("Fists", false, 10.0, 5, 1.0, xcord, ycord)
```

You are constructing a temp `Weapon` and then trying to construct `m_Weapon` from that temp.  Presumably `Weapon` does not have a copy constructor that takes a `Weapon` as input.